# how to download Gurobi (v9.0.3) in python (v3.8)?

Tags: python-3.8, gurobi

I am looking to download Gurobi in python but when I follow gurobi's instructions to do so, I get this error.

Python installation directory (hit ENTER to use c:\Python27):

The system cannot find the path specified.

[Hit ENTER to exit]

Please let me know if anyone has recently done this and can share some insight.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you "download Gurobi in Python"? You can either install it via Anaconda:

```
conda config --add channels http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi
conda install gurobi
```

Or you can start up any Python environment and run this from within the GUROBI_HOME installation directory:

```
python setup.py install
```

Check out this [guide for more detailed instructions](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044290292-How-do-I-install-Gurobi-for-Python-).